# Can I send a Whatsapp for a reminder to my customer

Tags: twilio

I'd like to send some reminders to my customers via Twilio-Whatsapp, but it is important for me to know that my customers don't have to remember to join my Twilio account to get informed. Just for now I'm trying the Twilio Whatsapp sandbox, but it works as I mentioned above... quite useless for my application. Can you tell me if "paid" account could work as I need ?
Thanks.
Over

Comment: You should ask the Twilio tech support.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should ask the Twilio tech support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

So, you've created a test app using the [Twilio API for WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp) and [the sandbox](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#twilio-sandbox-for-whatsapp) that it provides to allow for testing.

Currently, WhatsApp are onboarding customers under their own conditions. If you want to use this in a production application you need to [request access from WhatsApp, which you can do through Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp/request-access). Once you are accepted and can upgrade one of your Twilio numbers to a WhatsApp enabled number, you will then be able to send reminders to your customers as long as your customers have explicitly opted in to receive messages from you over WhatsApp and that you are [using templates to send messages when outside of a conversation session](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#send-a-whatsapp-message-using-a-template).

Comment: Ok Phil, thanks, I read I should create a Facebook Business Manager account, is that mandatory ? Thanks.

Comment: As part of going through the process with Twilio, we will set you up with that account. I'd recommend getting in touch directly with the [sales team](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) to discuss this in more depth.